# Able to receive, but not send email over SMTP from VPS. I don't think I'm being blacklisted

Tags: ubuntu, email, dns, smtp, vps

The error I get is "421 Downstream server error" or something similar. Up until a few days ago I could send mail without any trouble. I've searched around, and most other people with this problem end up having issues with reverse DNS, but I tested my rDNS setup by connecting to my home machine, which showed the correct IP and domain name.

Port 25 is not being filtered, I portscanned the machine using some 3rd party service, which reported port 25 as being open. I have SPF, DKIM and MX records attached to my domain name. I checked blacklists for both my IP and my domain name, and I'm not on any of them.

The remote SMTP server hangs after HELO, and replies with a 421 a few seconds later.

Any help on resolving this issue is much appreciated.

EDIT: more information

- I'm running Ubuntu 12.04
- My MTA is Postfix
- My domain name is mapariensis.eu

Comment: This likely indicates that the downstream server can't accept mail right now. Is your mail server trying to send to destinations directly? Or do you have a mail provider that you forward mail to?

Comment: I'm trying to send to destinations directly. I don't think it's a problem on the remote end, because I get the same issues with any destination. I tried sending messages to google, hotmail and even my university's mail server, and I got the same issue every time (timeout after HELO). About 5 days ago I could mail to google and my uni's addresses just fine. I didn't test hotmail, though.

Comment: If you get the same unusual error message when you connect to each of several unrelated downstreams, then something is likely intercepting your connections. Otherwise, it's an incredible coincidence.

Comment: Any idea what that something could be? If it's not something standard I'm overlooking, I'll submit a ticket with my hosting provider.

Comment: If you call one phone number and a strange voice says "nobody home", and then you call an unrelated number and get the same voice giving the same message, your phone is broken.

Comment: I guess I'll file a ticket when I get home, then. Thanks!